# issue with setOnPageChangeListener

Tags: android, android-pageradapter

I have issue with `setOnPageChangeListener`. Please help me out to solve this problem.

When I run my app without `setOnPageChangeListener` it works good, but with this it get crashed and show this message:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$OnPageChangeListener)' on a null object reference

```
public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager _mViewPager;
    private ImageView _btn1, _btn2, _btn3;
    private Dialog view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        ReplaceFont.replaceDefaultFont(this, "DEFAULT", "arial.ttf");
        initialisePaging();
        onCircleButtonClick();
        setTab();

    }


    private void initialisePaging(){

        List<Fragment> fragments= new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, ImageOne.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, ImageTwo.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, ImageThree.class.getName()));

        mPagerAdapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.vgeView);
        pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        initButton();
    }
    private void onCircleButtonClick() {

        _btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                _btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.fill_circle);
                _mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            }
        });

        _btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                _btn2.setImageResource(R.drawable.fill_circle);
                _mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            }
        });
        _btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                _btn3.setImageResource(R.drawable.fill_circle);
                _mViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
            }
        });
    }
    private void setTab() {
        _mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int position) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                _btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.holo_circle);
                _btn2.setImageResource(R.drawable.holo_circle);
                _btn3.setImageResource(R.drawable.holo_circle);
                btnAction(position);
            }

        });

    }
    private void btnAction(int action) {
        switch (action) {
            case 0:
                _btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.fill_circle);

                break;

            case 1:
                _btn2.setImageResource(R.drawable.fill_circle);

                break;
            case 2:
                _btn3.setImageResource(R.drawable.fill_circle);

                break;
        }
    }

    private void initButton() {
        _btn1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        _btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.fill_circle);
        _btn2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        _btn3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btn3);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your method initialisePaging where you initialize the viewPager your are creating a new one and not using the one declare as global (_mViewPager).   In order to solve it you will need to change the following:

```
 ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.vgeView);
```

for:

```
 _mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.vgeView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a global variable, `private ViewPager _mViewPager;`
but did not assign any reference to it. And created a local variable for ViewPager. `ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.vgeView);`

Then you are trying to use the global variable to set OnPageChangeListener.
`_mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener()`.

here, _mViewPager is null.

So, you have to change the line, 
`ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.vgeView);` 
to `_mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.vgeView);`

Answer (score 0):

hmm your _mViewPager is not instanciated.

replace

```
private void initialisePaging(){

List<Fragment> fragments= new Vector<Fragment>();
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, ImageOne.class.getName()));
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, ImageTwo.class.getName()));
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, ImageThree.class.getName()));

mPagerAdapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments);
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.vgeView);
pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
initButton();}
```

with this

```
enter code private void initialisePaging(){

List<Fragment> fragments= new Vector<Fragment>();
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, ImageOne.class.getName()));
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, ImageTwo.class.getName()));
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, ImageThree.class.getName()));

mPagerAdapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments);
_mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.vgeView);
_mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
initButton();}
```